# Poedit alternative for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, translation

I need an alternative to [Poedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poedit)¹ which can suggest translations from an <strike>online</strike> source. I'm going to use it to translate WordPress (CMS) themes / plugins. The program should be free or open source. My language is Turkish. Here's the requirements:

- Works for WordPress
- Runs on Windows or Linux (Windows preferred)
- Free or open source
- Can suggest translation from previously added / suggested translation at any source (online source preferred)
- English and Turkish support

---

¹ <sub>a cross-platform [gettext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) catalog (`.po` file) editor to aid in the process of language localisation.</sub>